# Get specific custom fields from JSON request in blade view Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have a JSON request from Upsales Api and I would like to pass the custom values in a blade view.

Here's my

```
$request = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $values = json_decode($request, true);
    //print_r($values);
    return view('test')->with('values',$values);
```

and here's the response

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 157
                    [name] => XXX XXX
                    [phone] => +46
                    [webpage] =>
                    [active] => 1
                    [users] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [custom] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => Svenljunga
                                    [valueArray] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Svenljunga
                                        )

                                [fieldId] => 9
                            )
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Västra Götaland
                                [valueArray] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Västra Götaland
                                    )
                                [fieldId] => 10
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

Here's my blade

```
@foreach ($values ['data'] as $m)
        <tbody>                                            
            <tr> 
                <td> {{ ($m['name']) }}</td>
                @foreach ($m['custom'] as $c )
                    @if ($c = 'fieldId = 9')
                        <td> {{ $c[0]['value']}} </td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                @foreach ($m['custom'] as $c )
                    @if ($c = 'fieldId = 10')
                        <td> {{ $c[0]['value']}} </td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>   
    @endforeach
```

I want to to parse the values of the 2 custom field in blade. I've tried for a couple of hours now, but I can't seem to figure out how I am able to get those values.

My problem is that there are a lot of custom fields and not on every company there filled in so the [3] and [4] can be different, but the feildId's are always the same. How can show the values of fielId 9 and 10?

Error message I got is "Illegal string offset 'value'".

can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
@foreach ($m['custom'] as $c )
    @if ($c['fieldId'] == '9' || $c['fieldId'] == '10')
         <td> {{ $c[0]['value']}} </td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me. It works. I had to remove the [0] aswell

Comment: @Danny, I am feeling happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($m['custom'] as $key=>$c ) 

 @if ($c['fieldId'] == '9')

 <td> {{ $c['value']}} </td>

 @endif
@endforeach
```

i think u can add $key to better check the loop

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This returned the same as I got without the if statement and the [0]. I had to use ==